# How to make a login window in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new at C# and can't get my username and password program to work.

I need to get the inputs from the user and check it against the account details which I've stored in a dictionary.

Comment: Your code seems ok, I suspect the problem is in the code you don't show. are you sure that you set `username` and `password` variables correctly?

Comment: I edited your question to correct the grammar and took the liberty of cropping the image to exclude the IDE. In case you are not happy with that, you can roll back the edit or make your own further edits.

Comment: thank you Andrew and @Gian Paolo the code works if I am not using the IDE but because I am using Unity I need to link the (username) and (password) to public GameObjects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `Console.WriteLine` does not work in Unity. You have to use [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html).

> I am new at C# and can't get my username and password program to work.

**1**.Create two [`InputFileds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html). One for *username* and one for *password*.

You can do that by going to *GameObject*-->*UI*-->*Input Field*

**2**.Create the Submit [`Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html).

You can do that by going to *GameObject*-->*UI*-->*Button*

**3**.Subscribe to the submit `Button` onClick event so that when it it clicked, the `adminDetails()` function will be called.

That's it. You can get the input with `InputField.text`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AdminLogin : MonoBehaviour
{

    public InputField userNameField;
    public InputField passwordField;
    public Button loginButton;

    void Start()
    {
        //Subscribe to onClick event
        loginButton.onClick.AddListener(adminDetails);
    }

    Dictionary<int, string> staffDetails = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {101,"femi1998" },
        {102,"kwaks1999" },
        {103,"eman1999" }
    };


    public void adminDetails()
    {
        //Get Username from Input then convert it to int
        int userName = Convert.ToInt32(userNameField.text);
        //Get Password from Input 
        string password = passwordField.text;

        string foundPassword;
        if (staffDetails.TryGetValue(userName, out foundPassword) && (foundPassword == password))
        {
            Debug.Log("User authenticated");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Invalid password");
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to drag both created `InputFields` and the `Button` to the *userNameField*, *passwordField* and *loginButton* slots in the Editor.

Comment: Double click on the on the error. It will show which line of code it happened on. Post that line of code in the comment

Comment: Forget about that. You get that error because `userNameField.text` is empty("") or you typed in string in the username box then tried to convert it to int.

Comment: Just replace `int userName = Convert.ToInt32(userNameField.text);` **with** `int userName;
        Int32.TryParse(passwordField.text, out userName);`

Comment: now it is saying the username and password is wrong, I printed out each stage and the username is coming back as 0

Comment: dw I changed the whole int part to a string to make it easier now the progam works with string username and stirng password Thank you

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I was wondering why you used int instead of string for username.